# Запуск скрипта powershell после загрузки и перед выключением системы?

Tags: powershell, windows-7

Как запустить скрипт powershell в windows 7 после загрузки и перед выключением системы?

Comment: Через планировщик, есссно.

Comment: @Akina, подскажите, пожалуйста, как это сделать?

Comment: Пуск - Панель управления - Администрирование - Планировщик заданий - Библиотека - Создать задание. В задании указываете нужные действия (запуск скрипта) и триггеры (на события - загрузку и на выключение).

Comment: @Akina спасибо. При запуске есть триггер, а перед выключении не могу найти. Возможно ли запланировать задание перед выключением системы?

Comment: Да, через соответствующее событие журнала. Какое именно - не помню, а искать лень. И учитывайте, что выключение бывает и без логона.

Comment: Есть ещё вариант - и он, наверное, даже лучше будет. gpedit - Конфигурация компьютера - Конфигурация Windows - Сценарии (запуск/завершение). Этот способ гарантирует, что сценарий будет выполнен до того, как компьютер окончательно выключится (а вот по журналу я такой гарантии бы не дал...). Но помните, что задания однопользовательского режима будут выполняться уже после такого сценария.

Comment: @Akina спасибо, значит через планировщик можно не создавать задание, а сразу в сценарии запуска и завершения прописать скрипты?

Comment: Да, именно так. В Windows вообще дофига мест, откуда что-то запускается, и в данном случае сценарии, вероятно, предпочтительнее.

Comment: @Akina спасибо за ответ, не знал про gpedit.